# Text To Speech With Custom Array-Adapter Android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have made a custom adapter and I now want to add a **text to speech** in its constructor but I don't know how to do this.

**MainActivity**

```
         ArrayList<Word> numbers = new ArrayList<Word>();

                //Initializing
                numbers.add(new Word("one", "uno", R.drawable._nmbericon));

                //this is how i want to pass my Pronunciation as the fourth parameter 
                // numbers.add(new Word("one", "onu", R.drawable._nmbericon,"unoo"));

                WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, numbers);
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//->> TEXT TO SPEECH STARTS HERE
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(NumbersActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInit(int status) {
                            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                                result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                                String toSpeak = "ONUU";
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                textToSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported in your Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
              //->> TEXT TO SPEECH ENDSHERE
```

**WordAdapter**

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

        //Constructor
        public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> word) { 
            super(context, 0, word);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if(listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            }
            Word CurrentWord = getItem(position);
            TextView spanish_text_view = (TextView) listItemView
                        .findViewById(R.id.spanish_text_view);
            TextView default_text_view = (TextView) listItemView
                        .findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
            default_text_view.setText(CurrentWord.getEnglishWords());
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(CurrentWord.getImageResourceid());
            View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textContainer);   
            return listItemView;
        }
    }
```

**Word**

```
public class Word {    
    //Varibles
    private String SpanishWords; //Spanish Word
    private String EnglishWords; //English translation of the Spanish word
    private int imageResourceid;
    private String pronunciation;

    public Word(String SpanishWords, String EnglishWords, int imageResourceid, String pronunciation) {
        this.SpanishWords= SpanishWords; //Since the name is the same use the this keyword
        this.EnglishWords = EnglishWords;
        this.imageResourceid = imageResourceid;
        this.pronunciation = pronunciation;
    }
    //getters
    public String getPronunciation() {
        return pronunciation;
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of the application]

So when I click on the `TextContainer`, the spanish word should be spoken (which is the fourth parameter in the `MainActivity` class).

So this is what I have so far but I am unable to get it to work. The app keeps crashing whenever I try to play it.
I really do not know how to use Text to Speech with custom `arrayAdapter`. 
If some one could point me the right direction, it would be really appreciated.
i want it to directly grab the text from the **MainActivity**  the fourth parameter in the Initializing place

Comment: Try to get TTS working just with a single value. Worry about the adapter & clicking piece later

Comment: i did that already please see the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed to fix it all i had to do was edit the `MainActivity` Java File
Like so

**MainActivity**

```
  final ArrayList<Word> numbers = new ArrayList<Word>(); //edited this

  numbers.add(new Word("one", "onu", R.drawable._nmbericon,"unoo"));

                    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, numbers);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //->> TEXT TO SPEECH STARTS HERE
          listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(NumbersActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInit(int status) {
                                  //And edited Here
                                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                                    result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                        Word num = numbers.get(position);
                        result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                        String toSpeak = num.getPronunciation();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textToSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported in your Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
                  //->> TEXT TO SPEECH ENDSHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

This Should work. 
take a look at [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) if you have issues with the language.

```
 textoSpeech=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               textoSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ES);
            }
         }
      });

      TextContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak = TextContainer.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textoSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
         }
      });
```

Hope i helped.